# White space/ bar at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I noticed that my web page has a white space/bar right after the footer and at the bottom of the page:

[image]

I tried to find the cause of this by using the inspect element in Chrome and can't find anything. I'm using Boostrap and here's my footer HTML/CSS:

```
 <div class="container">
    <hr>
  </div> <!--end container-->
  <div id="footer">
    <footer class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="mail"> <a href="mailto:info@8delfiini.ee" title="Kirjuta mulle!"><img src="images/mail.png" alt="e-kiri" title="Kirjuta mulle!"/></a>
          <p><a href="mailto:info@8delfiini.ee">info@8delfiini.ee</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="tel"> <a href="tel:+3725299131" title="Helista mulle!"><img src="images/phone.png" alt="telefon" title="Helista mulle!"/></a>
          <p><a href="tel:+3725299131">(+372) 52 99 131</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="addr"> <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/ny3wV" title="Asukoht" target="_blank"><img src="images/location.png" alt="asukoht" title="Asukoht"/></a> <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/ny3wV" title="Asukoht" target="_blank">
          <p>Jansuki Shop<br />
            Müürivahe 17<br />
            Tallinn </p>
          </a> </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="fb"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/8Delfiini" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"/></a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/8Delfiini" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
          <p>8 Delfiini Facebookis</p>
          </a> </div>
      </div>
      <!--end row--> 
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!--end footer-->
```

And the CSS for the whole contact page:

```
 /*kontakt*/

#kontakt
{
    background: url(../images/IMG_1340.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2.cont-heading
{
    background: url(../images/kontakt.png) no-repeat 0 155px;
    background-size: 48.5px 53px;
    padding: 160px 0 5px 60px;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1.invitation
{
    font-family: 'latoregular', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size: 7em;
}

#logo
{
    width: 28px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#part3, #part4
{
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 0;
}

#part4
{
    padding: 30px;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

hr
{
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0.4), rgba(255,255,255,0.75), rgba(255,255,255,0.4));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0.4), rgba(255,255,255,0.75), rgba(255,255,255,0.4));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0.4), rgba(255,255,255,0.75), rgba(255,255,255,0.4));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0.4), rgba(255,255,255,0.75), rgba(255,255,255,0.4));
}

/*footer styles*/

#footer
{
    padding: 40px;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    text-align: center;
}

#footer a
{
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

#mail img, #tel img, #addr img, #fb img
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#mail a, #tel a, #addr a, #fb a
{
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: 'latoregular', sans-serif;
}
```

I'm new to Bootstrap. Is there maybe something special in its CSS that causes this? Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Do footer { margin-bottom:-20px;}

Comment: @Ali Gagjani - Seriously?

Comment: Not working unfortunately.

Comment: put the link to your page here then i can inspect

Comment: @LGVentura - Ok, here it is: http://eka.webweaver.ee/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by setting a *padding* for the #footer .row:

```
#footer .container .row {
    padding-bottom:8px;
}
```

<sup><sub>*Beautiful layout btw :)*</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you, it's working. And thank you for you kind words. :)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of things has mostly to do with not setting the body style:

```
body
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

It can also happen that you have set the heights of other elements wrongly.
It's a good practice to reset all the predefined styles, see http://www.cssreset.com/

And just to be sure; your background image is big enough, right?

Comment: This solution is not working as well. Bootstrap has already set the body margin to 0. The background photo seems to big enough (height 1333px). There seems to be something else wrong there...

Comment: Can you share a test link, the provided CSS is not sufficient to solve the problem as it doesn't contain everything.

Comment: The heights in footer are incorrect. Adjust your padding there and the white line will disappear.